# How should I deal with saving foreign key?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have two models `Order` and `OrderItem`.

```
class OrderItem(SmartModel):
    shopping_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,db_index=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
```

this is how am creating and saving `OrderItem` object

```
if not item_in_orders:
        # creat and save a new order item
        anon_user = User.objects.get(id=settings.ANONYMOUS_USER_ID) 
        try:
            order= Order.objects.get(pk=order_id)
        except:
            order = Order.objects.create(created_by=anon_user,modified_by=anon_user)

        oi=OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,shopping_id=_shopping_id(request),
                                          quantity=quantity,
                                          item=i,
                                          created_by=anon_user,
                                          modified_by=anon_user)
        oi.save()
```

Now i should mention that `OrderItem` object above is created before the `Order` object.

```
class Order(SmartModel):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,help_text="Needed as alternative")
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(max_length=20,default='+2507####')
    billing_name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    billing_address= models.CharField(max_length=50)    
    billing_city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

both models are ModelForms and are validated fine except that when the two are created, two rows in the database are created for `Order`. The first row which is not populated i suspect is created by this code when am creating the OrderItem.

```
order = Order.objects.create(created_by=anon_user,modified_by=anon_user)

            oi=OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,shopping_id=_shopping_id(request),
                                              quantity=quantity,
                                              item=i,
                                              created_by=anon_user,
                                              modified_by=anon_user)
            oi.save()
```

The second row is created when i save the `Order` object and is fine.

Keep in mind that `OrderItem` is created before `Order` and the later is a foreignkey field in the former.

My requirement for my django app is that an order item is created before customer (in my case `Order`) are given. Any other ideas are welcome.

Comment: what is the role 0f  i?

Comment: How come order item create before order? order item needs order foreign key

Comment: @masterofdestiny `i` is mislabelled variable that holds an item,will change its name but its not the problem, i can asure you. I posted less code,usually i dont get much help because of posting too much code in my questions. so i posted the necessary.

Comment: @catherine now the reason i do that, is cause after customers create order items then they can provide there details which is `Order`,if there is another way i can go about this please advice me.

Comment: If that's the case you can access the order even though it is save first, do you like that suggestion? I will change my answer?

Comment: @catherine dont get it wrong, Order is not saved first Orderitem is..

Comment: yeah I know what you mean, but it is impossible to save order item without the order foreign key. What I just telling you is we can access that order if you want to add something like the info of the user as what you said earlier

Answer (score 0):

OK As you said

Keep in mind that OrderItem is created before Order and the later is a foreignkey field in the former.

Then in this case you should design your model like

```
class OrderItem(SmartModel):
    shopping_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,db_index=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,blank=True,null = True)
```

Here i am giving you how can you save `Foreign key` value in the table

In the query

```
order = Order.objects.create(created_by=anon_user,modified_by=anon_user)

            oi=OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,shopping_id=_shopping_id(request),
                                              quantity=quantity,
                                              item=i,
                                              created_by=anon_user,
                                              modified_by=anon_user)
            oi.save()
```

I dont know what is `i`  But if you are going to save the Foreign key then `i`  must me instance of `Item`

I am just asuming a simple example suppose if you are getting the `itemname`  from form first you have to filter that in `Item`  table .

Like     `getitem = Item.objects.get(name= itemname)`

And then you can save your foreign key like

```
order = Order.objects.create(created_by=anon_user,modified_by=anon_user)

            oi=OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,shopping_id=_shopping_id(request),
                                              quantity=quantity,
                                              item=getitem,
                                              created_by=anon_user,
                                              modified_by=anon_user)
            oi.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are

1. Creating a blank Order to save with the OrderItem (to satisfy the foreign key)
2. Creating another fully populated Order after creating the OrderItem (since you mention Order is created after OrderItem). I am assuming, this is not shown in your code above.

This is why you are seeing two Order instances being created.

Instead of creating a new Order the second time (Step 2), you could update the Order you created in Step 1 with the order information, such as email, address etc. and save it.

**EDIT: Added detailed how-to...**

There would be some place in your code where you are creating the second Order. Instead of creating a new Order there, use the reference to the Order created in Step 1 (the order variable in the code you posted), update it with email and address information once it is available and call save() on it. This will update the order in the database instead of creating a new instance.

Comment: You my friend have understood my problem(craziness),what do you need to see from my code to help me solve this problem.i posted less code not to bore people

Comment: I have added more details. I hope this makes it clear how you can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
order = Order.object.create(
    created_by=anon_user, 
    modified_by=anon_user
    )


OrderItem.object.create(
    order = order, 
    shopping_id = _shopping_id(request),
    quantity=quantity,
    item=i,
    created_by=anon_user,
    modified_by=anon_user
    )

//To access the order after saving the above info
//For example:

order.email = 'anyone@gmail.com'
order.save()
```

Comment: uhmm..that dont work either, creates three rows in database..ok, what other way would return an order item and customers info as one object without using a foreign key.

Comment: if you like I want to see your codes and fix it. Just send me the whole project. We can't understand here and it's hard to teach you here.

Comment: for real,awsome just please tell me how i should do that, am new in this developing field..

Comment: I do this sometimes for others, if we are having long conversation.

Comment: you just have to compress your project before attach

Comment: yeah, I'm currently downloaded it. I will just tell you if I finish it? Where I will send it after I finish?

Comment: are you sure it's 25mb? it's 48mb+ and still currently downloading

Comment: what's the real capacity of your project? It's really big, I'm not finish yet downloading

Comment: where are your settings, wsgi, urlconf here? I can't run your project

Comment: ..f4l/f4l/settings.py,url.py e.t.c